# Spring Batch Integration - pass data b/w integration and batch

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch

I am using Spring Batch Integration as I have to perform certain works before invoking the batch.

I have done the work using Spring Integration and invoke the batch using job-launching-gateway and it works like a charm.
Now the question is how to pass the data from Spring Integration to Batch?

Suggestions please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message sent to the `JobLaunchingGateway` has a `JobLaunchRequest` payload.

When you build the request in your Spring Integration flow, you can add `JobParameters` which are then used within the batch job.

**EDIT**

For custom objects you would have to do it indirectly. For example via a `Map`.

If you are using XML configuration, you can use a:

`<util:map id="jobParams"> ... </...>`

Stuff your object into the map under some key, pass the key as a `JobParameter`, `@Autowire` the map into your batch job and retrieve/remove the object using the key.

Comment: yes Agree, but JobParameters wont accept custom objects. I want to pass the custom object that I got from Integration to batch.

Comment: Thanks Gary for your hint..can we send the message over queue channel and receive it from batch?

Comment: Yes; the channel type is not important.